# Compare values in C# list

Tags: c#, .net, fuzzy-comparison

I'm using fuzzyString to buy names from my list. I have a class `Customer` in which I want to compare a name with all other existing names.

My `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int NIF { get; set; }
    public string NewName { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

In this code, I get the data from an Excel sheet and put it in the list. Now I want to compare the names:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var customer = ReadXls();

    foreach (var item in customer)
    {
        // Console.WriteLine($"Name:{item.Name}\n Phone:{item.Phone}\nContact:{item.Contact}\nEmail:{item.Email}\n");

        List<FuzzyStringComparisonOptions> options = new List<FuzzyStringComparisonOptions>();

        // Choose which algorithms should weigh in for the comparison
        options.Add(FuzzyStringComparisonOptions.UseOverlapCoefficient);
        options.Add(FuzzyStringComparisonOptions.UseLongestCommonSubsequence);
        options.Add(FuzzyStringComparisonOptions.UseLongestCommonSubstring);

        // Choose the relative strength of the comparison - is it almost exactly equal? or is it just close?
        FuzzyStringComparisonTolerance tolerance = FuzzyStringComparisonTolerance.Normal;

        bool result = item.Name.ApproximatelyEquals(item.Name, options, tolerance);

        // Get a boolean determination of approximate equality
        // double simLevenshtein = 1 - source.sor(target);
        double hamming = item.Name.HammingDistance(item.Name);
        double jaccard = item.Name.JaccardDistance(item.Name);
        double jaro = item.Name.JaroDistance(item.Name);

        double lev = item.Name.LevenshteinDistance(item.Name);

        Console.WriteLine(result + " " + hamming + " " + jaccard + " " + jaro+" " + lev);
            
        if (result == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Name:{item.Name}\n Phone:{item.Phone}\nContact:{item.Contact}\nEmail:{item.Email}\n");
    }
}

private static List<Customer> ReadXls()
{
    var response = new List<Customer>();

    string FileName;
    Console.WriteLine("Diretório do ficheiro:");
    FileName = Console.ReadLine();

    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FileName);

    ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[0];

        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;

        int row = 2;
        int col = 1;

        while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value?.ToString()) == false)
        {
            Customer customer = new Customer();

            customer.Name = worksheet.Cells[row, 4].Text.Trim().ToUpper();
            customer.Phone = worksheet.Cells[row, 5].Text.Trim();

            // customer.Phone = Regex.Replace(customer.Phone, "\\+[0-9] {1,}", "");
            customer.Phone = Regex.Replace(customer.Phone, @"\s", "");
            customer.Phone = customer.Phone.Replace("+351", "");
            customer.Phone = customer.Phone.Replace("+44", "");
            customer.Phone = customer.Phone.Replace("+34", "");
            customer.Phone = customer.Phone.Replace("+244", "");
            customer.Phone = customer.Phone.Replace("+33", "");
            customer.Phone = customer.Phone.Replace("+49", "");

            customer.Contact = worksheet.Cells[row, 7].Text.Trim().ToLower();
            customer.Contact = UppercaseWords(customer.Contact);

            customer.Email = worksheet.Cells[row, 8].Text.Trim().ToLower();

            response.Add(customer);

            row += 1;
        }
    }

    return response;
}
```

With this code it only compares the `Customer.Name` with the same `Customer.Name`.. ex:

```
1 compares with 1 |
2 compares with 2 |
3 compares with 3 |
```

But I need that:

```
1 compares with 2 and 3 |

2 compares with 1 and 3 |

3 compares with 1 and 2 |
```

Comment: That's a big block of code, without much explanation, but you essentially seem to be complaining that names are only compared with themselves.. You've written e.g. `item.Name.HammingDistance(item.Name);` which is the only "looks like it compares" code I can see.. and it compares the item with itself.. So essentially you appear to have implemented your complaint?

Comment: If you want to compare items in a list with every other (not itself) item in a list, you need two loops: `for(var a in list){ for(var b in list) { if(a==b) continue; else a.CompareTo(b); }}`